# Jquery open/close variable for adding and removing class

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

As you can see i want to do and if/else statement for adding and removing classes. But the if/else statematen below isn't really working for me, it adds the classes but it doesn't remove them again, when i click second time.

```
    function showAndHidediv(id, liName) {
        $("#" + id).toggle(function () {
            $("#" + id).animate({
               display: 'block'
            }, 500);

            var open = "closed";

            if (open == "open") {
                $("#" + liName + " a").removeClass('color');
                $("#" + liName + " a div").removeClass('block');
                $("#" + liName + " img").removeClass('block');
                open = "closed";
            } else {
                $("#" + liName + " a").addClass('color');
                $("#" + liName + " a div").addClass('block');
                $("#" + liName + " img").addClass('block');
                open = "open";
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: try to declare your variable `open` globally, thus outside your function `showAndHidediv`. Everytime this function gets calles in the moment, your variable gets overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use toggle class to resolve your problem.

In above code snippet you have taken local JS variable.i.e.var open = "closed";

So everytime its gatting reset.

Try declaring 'open' variable globally and then check. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery it would be more convenient to use built-in function `toggleClass()`:

```
$( "p" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight" );
});
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/fgtL6dv4/)

And your case:

```
function showAndHidediv(id, liName) {
    $("#" + id).toggle(function () {
        $("#" + id).animate({
           display: 'block'
        }, 500);

        $("#" + liName + " a").toggleClass('color');
        $("#" + liName + " a div").toggleClass('block');
        $("#" + liName + " img").toggleClass('block');
    });
}
```

Comment: @user3661240, can you provide fiddle so we can check your case?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
function showAndHidediv(id, liName) {
            $("#" + id).toggle(function () {
                $("#" + id).animate({
                   display: 'block'
                }, 500);

                var open = false;

                if (open == "open") {
                    $("#" + liName + " a").removeClass('color');
                    $("#" + liName + " a div").removeClass('block');
                    $("#" + liName + " img").removeClass('block');
                    open =false;
                } else {
                    $("#" + liName + " a").addClass('color');
                    $("#" + liName + " a div").addClass('block');
                    $("#" + liName + " img").addClass('block');
                    open = true;
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it only adds the class and doesn't remove it, but thanks anyway :)